# mininet simulation without controller and with

Tags: networking, simulation, sdn, mininet, openflow

Whats the difference between using mininet simulation without controller and with controller? Whats the point to use simulation without controller?

Sorry for noob question.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The Mininet network without a controller is a collection of virtual switches and hosts. You can still interact with hosts and use ovs-ofctl to configure flows on the switches, but this would make you the controller.

Using a controller with Mininet doesn't guarantee anything, it is up to the applications configured on the controller to control the network, but ideally the controller is running a L2 learning switch application to give you some network functionality.